# ubuntu unable to reach the wifi login link but wifi connected

Tags: networking

i am new to ubuntu 16.04 and i am facing problem with my wifi settings. I recently attempted to set up a static IP on my Ubuntu,using the link below,

http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F338442%2Fhow-to-set-static-ip-address&h=XAQGgM9wm&s=1

but when I opened the login link in my browser, the site is unreachable.
The configuration of my wifi network is as follows:
IP Address:192.168.100.11
netmask: 255.255.255.0
DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
Gateway: 192.168.100.1

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it so much! Thank you!

Comment: Is that IP taken by some other device on the LAN?